# can not get value of TempData[" "] in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i set a data in TempData[""] in one action which is type of [HttpGet] and want to get this data in [HttpPost].i just set data in that tepmdata variable conditionally.but i can get that tempdata variable in [HttpPost] if the condition in [httpget] is else.but if that condition is true then i get that tempdata variiable as null only.i don't know the reason why i am getting null.
this is [httpget] action.and TempData["jobid"] is my variable.

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CreateBidFirstStep(string id)
    {
        BiddingFirstStepModel _objBiddingFirstStepModel = new BiddingFirstStepModel();
        _objBiddingFirstStepModel.DepartmentList = new SelectList(_objBiddingFirstStepBDC.GetDepartments(), "DepartmentId", "DepartmentName");
        _objBiddingFirstStepModel.JobTypeList = new SelectList(_objBiddingFirstStepBDC.GetJobtypes(), "JobTypeId", "JobType");
        _objBiddingFirstStepModel.CustomersList = new SelectList(_objBiddingFirstStepBDC.GetCustomers(), "CustomerId", "CustomerName");
        if (id != null)
        {

            _objBiddingFirstStepModel.isedit = true;
            _objBiddingFirstStepModel.jobdata = _objBiddingFirstStepBDC.GetJobDetailById(id);
            TempData["jobid"] = id;
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["jobid"] = "abc";
        }
        _objBiddingFirstStepModel.CustomersList = new SelectList(_objBiddingFirstStepBDC.GetCustomers(), "Id", "CustomerName");
        Logger.Info("Logger is working here");

        return View(_objBiddingFirstStepModel);

    }
```

this is my [HttpPost] action.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateBidFirstStep(BiddingFirstStepModel formdata)
    {
        //-------------To get all departments------------

        formdata.DepartmentList = new SelectList(_objBiddingFirstStepBDC.GetDepartments(), "DepartmentId", "DepartmentName");
        List<SelectListItem> department = new List<SelectListItem>();
        department = formdata.DepartmentList.ToList();

        JobDTO jobdata = new JobDTO();
        DocumentLatestDTO document = new DocumentLatestDTO();

        //---------To insert Job data-----------

        jobdata.JobName = formdata.jobname;
        jobdata.JobType = formdata.jobtype;
        jobdata.JobTypeId = formdata.jobtypeid;
        jobdata.CustomerName = formdata.customerid.ToString();
        jobdata.JobRefence = formdata.jobreference;
        jobdata.Quantity = formdata.quantity;
        jobdata.AreaOfPCB = formdata.area;
        jobdata.NumberOfJoints = formdata.jointsnumber;
        jobdata.Department = formdata.department;
        jobdata.DepartmentId = formdata.departmentid;
        jobdata.Status = false;
        jobdata.JobDescription = formdata.description;
        jobdata.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
        jobdata.CompleteOn = formdata.datepickerEndDate;
        jobdata.Tasktypeid = 1;
        string job = (string)TempData["jobid"];
        if (job== "abc")
        {
        jobdata.NewJobId = _objBiddingFirstStepBDC.Addjobdatatoserver(jobdata);
        }
        else
        {
            BiddingDTO biddingobj=new BiddingDTO();
            biddingobj.jobid=TempData["jobid"].ToString();
            jobdata.JobId = TempData["jobid"].ToString();
            _objBiddingFirstStepBDC.Updatejobdatatoserver(jobdata);
            _objBiddingFirstStepBDC.ReviseBidding(biddingobj);
        }
        //---------To get and save uploaded bom---------

        if (formdata.excelbom != null && formdata.excelbom.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            document.JobId = jobdata.NewJobId;
            document.Department = jobdata.Department;
            document.DocumentName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(formdata.excelbom.FileName);
            document.DocumentExtension = Path.GetExtension(formdata.excelbom.FileName);
            document.Size = formdata.excelbom.ContentLength;
            document.UploadedBy = "Jitender Singh";
            document.UploadedOn = DateTime.Now;
            document.DocumentType = "BOM";

            FolderCreationUtility foldercreation = new FolderCreationUtility();
            foldercreation.CreateFolder(document, department, PathToSaveDocument);

            document.Path = _objBiddingFirstStepBDC.CreateDocumentPath(document);

            formdata.excelbom.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(PathToSaveDocument + document.Path));
        }
        Logger.Info("Logger is working here");
        return RedirectToAction("CreateBidSecondStep");
    }
```

please help me why i can not get value if i set my id in TempData in HttpGet action.

Comment: you know tempdata right?? it can hold value only once per request.I just want to be sure whether you are checking your `TempData` after using it once

Comment: i set a value in tempdata in httpget method and first time use at here:-
string job = (string)TempData["jobid"];
but i am getting error on this line:-
object refrence not set to an instance